# anltr4 visitor doesn't visit nodes in parse tree

Tags: java, antlr

I have a simple application that uses ANTLR4 to process `Java` file.

```
InputStream stream = String.class.getResourceAsStream("/sample-function.java");

Java8Lexer lexer = new Java8Lexer(CharStreams.fromStream(stream));
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
Java8Parser parser = new Java8Parser(tokens);
ParseTree tree = parser.compilationUnit();

HighLevelClassVisitor visitor = new HighLevelClassVisitor();
System.out.println(visitor.visit(tree).toString());
```

I created a simple visitor that should return `string` upon finishing visiting all parse tree nodes.

```
public class HighLevelClassVisitor extends Java8BaseVisitor<StringBuilder> {

    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    @Override
    public StringBuilder visitPackageDeclaration(PackageDeclarationContext ctx) {
        sb.append("Package declaration: ").append(ctx.packageName().getText());
        return sb;
    }

    @Override
    public StringBuilder visitNormalClassDeclaration(NormalClassDeclarationContext ctx) {
        sb.append("Class normal declaration: class ").append(ctx.Identifier().getText());
        return sb;
    }

    @Override
    public StringBuilder visitClassModifier(ClassModifierContext ctx) {
        sb.append("Class modifier: ").append(ctx.getText());
        return sb;
    }
}
```

But when I execute the application, it returns `null` as `visit` method result. When I put some `system.out` calls inside visit method it displays nothing. It seems it doesn't visit nodes at all. On the other side, `listener` worked just fine.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have not overriden the `visitor.visit(tree)` method, which is, in its abstract implementation, returns null.

The point of a visitor pattern (unlike listener) is that **you decide** which nodes to visit. You may visit all of them, visit only ones you need, or do not visit anything at all.

So, the solution to your problem would be either:

- Override `visit(ParseTree)` method in your `HighLevelClassVisitor` class and provide proper implementation (you would also need to implement `visitCompilationUnit()`, I guess).
- or, simply visit only those parts of tree, you're really interested in, i.e.:

```java
    PackageDeclarationContext ctx = parser.packageDeclaration();
    HighLevelClassVisitor visitor = new HighLevelClassVisitor();
    System.out.println(visitor.visitPackageDeclaration(ctx).toString());
```